# Moveit: getCurrentJointValues() won't update

Tags: ros, moveit, youbot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setup: ubuntu 14.04 LTS, ROS indigo, moveit, youbot in vrep simulator
Problem Description: I have a node from vrep publishing to topic /joint_states. Then I run the demo.launch from config pkg, commenting out the joint_state_publisher node. Finally, when I test my own code, calling the getCurrentJointValues() function, the returned joint values stay the default values not updated.

The code I write is very similar to Move Group Interface Tutorial.

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("youbot_arm");
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan my_plan;
moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;
std::vector<double> group_variable_values;
group.startStateMonitor();
group_variable_values = group.getCurrentJointValues();
while(1){ 
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("current joint value:");
    for(int k = 0;k < group_variable_values.size();k++){
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(group_variable_values[k]<<",");
    }
    sleep(3.0);
}
```

From the output of rostopic echo /joint_states, I get the joint position for "arm_joint_1". "arm_joint_2", "arm_joint_3", "arm_joint_4", "arm_joint_5" are 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0.
However, I get 2.94961, 1.35263, -2.59181, 0, 0 from my program, which is a default value I believe.
Also, the rviz bring up by demo.launch indeed can show the correct current position of the robot, can the gui planning module works just fine. I just can't access the current state from code.

Can anyone tell me any possible directions I should go?
Thank you very much!

wei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281008/moveit:-getcurrentjointvalues()-won%27t-update/) by [weitang](https://answers.ros.org/users/33263/weitang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-27**:
I don't think you can use `demo.launch` in the way you describe. Can you clarify what you changed exactly?

**Comment by [weitang](https://answers.ros.org/users/33263/weitang/) on 2018-01-27**:
In the demo.launch, since there is no real robot, so there is this fake joint state publisher, publishing to /joint_states. I already have a node publishing this message, so I delete this fake joint state publisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue. It may not be the same situation for everyone, But I post it here for future reference.
I compiled moveit from source and run the same program, first, it shows:
"Failed to fetch the current state"
Then I did the following change,
In moveit/moveit_ros/planning/planning_scene_monitor/src/current_state_monitor.cpp

I add a  ros::spinOnce()  at line 273 within the waitForCurrentState() function, because it seems the problem is the joint state callback function never get called. After I did this change, it works and can correctly get the current joint values.

---

Originally posted by [weitang](https://answers.ros.org/users/33263/weitang/) with karma: 31 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0